# How to delete messages from an exim mailbox older than a specified number of days

Tags: exim

I've spent quite some time trying to figure out how to do this but it seems I'm a bit at a loss. There must be a way to do this on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

`exim` is an MTA and should not manage mailboxes. You have to pass all incoming messages to the `dovecot-lda` that do all the rest. Also `dovecot` bundle contains a very useful utility called `doveadm`. Its functionality also include the old messages purge. You can add the next lines to the crontab:

```
31 0 * * * /path/doveadm expunge -A mailbox Junk  savedbefore 31d
41 0 * * * /path/doveadm expunge -A mailbox Trash savedbefore 31d
```

Here old messages are removed from "Trash" and "Spam" folders only.

I think it is a **very bad** idea to remove users messages automatically. It is much better to set quotas for mailboxes sizes and to send notification about reaching 75% and 95% of limit.

All that things are very good explained in the dovecot's wiki: http://wiki.dovecot.org/

Comment: Thanks. Just for reference - It is not for the mailbox of users as this would be dumb. It is basically a system working with a mailer's mailbox to check if people's mail are bouncing (returned) - when mail is returned the user is alerted that his email address is not working when logged in from the web. (A whole web back-end sits behind everything)

Comment: `exim` has its own functionality for the queue cleanup - `exim -Mrm <message-id>`. When message is submitted by user the corresponding logfile named after message-id is created. If message is successfully sended out the logfile is deleted. If no - there is some trouble here and you can discover the reason from that file. Also you can proceed all the logfiles by `find`, `grep` etc and launch the `exim -Mrm <logfilename>` to terminate all the sessions on some criteria.

Comment: Aaaaand, I'm geoblocked. Can't view the dovecot site. Great. :/